# What is the best way to draw chemical structures in LaTeX?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was just wondering what the best option is for getting chemical structures/reactions in LaTeX. Should I just draw the molecule in ChemDraw/ChemSketch then export it to LaTeX or is there a particular set of packages that would be better in the long run?

Thanks!

Comment: [Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722)